# Problems with Fragment lifecycle and onCreate being called on non existent fragment

Tags: android, lifecycle, fragment

I am testing fragments in Android and I'm having some confusing behavior with Fragment life cycle.   I have a activity that uses layouts in xml for both landscape and portrait modes.   I have some code that accesses a EditText object that is defined in one of the fragment layouts.   If I start the app in landscape mode things work.  I access the component in the onResume() fragment method to update some text.

According to the documentation the onResume() fragment method is called when the fragment is visible to the user.  However, if I rotate the screen this method gets called again even though this fragment is not defined in the portrait layout.   This call to onCreate causes a NullPointerException becuase this method references the EditText object.  Why is onResume method called on a fragment that is not part of the new layout?    How and where is the proper place to modify layout data in a fragment.  I have tried onStart, onResume, onActivityCreated etc, but all seem to return the same error.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Is onCreateView() also called in the fragment that is not part of the new layout?  If so, then you can be sure that you are instantiating this fragment somewhere - every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rotate the screen, Android saves your fragments in a Bundle and recreates them when it recreates the activity. That is why you get calls to a non-existing (actually just invisible) fragment. You need to handle this situation in the fragment code, or simply have both fragments in the land and port layouts, where you set the fragment visibility to `GONE` if you don't need it.

A simple way to check if the fragment is visible in code is this:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
  }
```

If `container` is null, your fragment is being re-created from a Bundle and won't be shown (since there is no container). You then have to check whether `getView()` is null and short-circuit your code accordingly. This can get messy though, so beware :)

Comment: thank you for the response i will try this later today.   The api for fragments seems out of sync with the documentation   I have found that i just cant rely on it

Comment: It's not out of sync, just not touching on some key points. Read the related blog entries on the Android developer's blog and pay attention to the example comments to get the full picture.

Comment: Thank you.  This is working OK for me now.  I ended up setting a flag in the onCreateView method and then checked this flag in onResume.   I still feel like this is a clumsy work around but for now it is working at least.

Comment: Yeah, I've done workarounds like that as well.  If it works fine with no bugs, then just go with it.