# Android: why fragments are started if they are not visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have two layouts for my `Activity`. First one is for landscape mode and contains two `FrameLayout`, second one is for portrait mode and contains only one `FrameLayout`. Fragments are added dynamically to respective `FrameLayouts`!! I'm not able to understand why when I rotate the screen in portrait mode `onStart()` and `onResume()` method of the Fragment (no more visible!!!!) are called. I know that Android replicates callbacks of the `Activity` for all of its Fragments but this behavior for me is a non sense!! `onStart()` and `onResume()` have to been called only when fragment comes visible!!!!

This issue has already been discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032565/problems-with-fragment-lifecycle-and-oncreate-being-called-on-non-existent-fragm). But I want to understand why Android has this behavior!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest, this will indicate you want to manage the orientation change by your own and don't need the default automanagement.
This will allow you to override onConfigurationChanged, check details at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html